# docker with maven jar

Tags: java, maven, docker

I'm running a maven project in a docker container, I'm getting Could not find or load main class error.

```
FROM maven:3.6.0-jdk-11-slim AS build

COPY src src
COPY pom.xml .
RUN mvn -f pom.xml clean package install

FROM openjdk:8-jre

COPY --from=build /target /opt/target
WORKDIR /target

RUN ls

CMD ["java", "-jar", "Customer.jar"]
```

above assembly was created with following plugin in `<build>`

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>com.companyname.Customer</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
            <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

**Error**

> Error: Could not find or load main class com.mycompany.Customer

Question: How do you set class path to a jar file in docker?

---

**Edit**

I tested with the following but same issue.

```
CMD ["java", "-cp", "Customer.jar:libs/*", "com.company.customers.Customer"]
```

> Error: Could not find or load main class
>   com.company.customers.Customer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a Docker issue it's a Java issue. There are several ways to define classpath entries to run an executable jar.

#### Shaded or Uber jar approach

In this case you sould create a shaded jar which contains all dependent classes in one executable jar file. Maven has a plugin called [Apache Maven Shade Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/index.html) to create that uber-jar artifact.

Finally just run:

```
java -jar shaded-artifact.jar
```

or in Docker

```
CMD ["java", "-jar", "shaded-artifact.jar"]
```

#### Command line classpath approach

If the created jar artifact requires the existence of other (dependent) jars you have to specify the classpath. In this case copy all required jars into a folder e.g. *lib* and use the following command:

```
java -cp '<name-of-jar.jar>:<path-of-dependencies>' <fully.quialified.main.ClassName>
```

As you can see either wildcard (*) character and multiple classpath element is allowed separated by `:`
so

```
java -cp 'Customer.jar:libs/*' com.mycompany.Customer
```

in Docker

```
CMD ["java", "-cp", "Customer.jar:libs/*", "com.mycompany.Customer"]
```

#### Classpath in MANIFEST approach

After you collecteded all those dependent artifact into a folder then you just add a `Class-Path` entry into your ***META-INF/MANIFEST.MF*** file like this:

```
Class-Path: . lib/*
```

and run

```
java -jar Customer.jar
```

or in Docker

```
CMD ["java", "-jar", "Customer.jar"]
```

Which of those is the best depends on so many things, you have to choose.

### Edit:

Based on updated question it seems the uber jar was created by assembly plugin using *jar-with-dependencies* predefined descriptor. This will create another jar file which placed under target (output) folder and its name ends with `-jar-with-dependencies.jar`

1. Use that jar insead of basic artifact.
2. Do a double check to make sure all of `<mainClass>` entries point to an existing class. You've mentioned three different main class in the same question.

   - > com.companyname.Customer
   - > com.mycompany.Customer
   - > com.company.customers.Customer
3. Pay attention for both of Linux and Java are case sensitive. On this basis the class name must be `Customer` exactly and all folder names must be lowercase.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how can I automate manifest entry via `maven-assembly-plugin`?

Comment: also I'm confused when you say `libs/*`, I don't have any libs folder inside my jar

Comment: Not inside the jar. You have to collect and copy those file into a folder out of the jar. Take a look at this: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-project-dependencies.html

Comment: is there a problem if I don't have a libs folder `libs/*`?

Comment: Considering the documentation `jar-with-dependencies provides only basic support for uber-jars. For more control, use the Maven Shade Plugin.`
In the `<manifest>` section you can add an entry `<addClasspath>true</addClasspath>`. To be honest I've never tried this.
More information is here: http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/index.html#class_manifest

Comment: hi zforgo, I'm on a time crunch, can you please help me out, look at my edits please. It's still not working

Comment: I'm pulling for you, @AppDeveloper but here is Sunday evening. Check my edit please.